# Eclipse : No Graphical Layout for Android XML Files

Tags: xml, eclipse, graphical-layout-editor

This problem occurred all of a sudden in my Eclipse(which happens to be fully updated) but it seems that my **Graphical Layout** editor is gone for ever.

I do not know what happened but graphical layout shows nothing even if there is code in XML. Even layout files of my previous projects stopped coming in the graphical editor.

This is all it shows me.

[image]

I even tried right clicking on the XML file in the package explorer and "Open with Default Editor" but still it does not work.

Can anyone PLEASE help ? I am totally stuck and it really **VERY** cumbersome to write all the layout codes in xml manually!

Comment: Anything in the Error Log view )or the error log itself)?

Comment: No, nothing. Only a blank screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case others come across the same problem, here is what worked for me :

I had to click and **select the API version** on the top-right corner of the graphical editor and then the layout would be displayed.

Moreover, I moved on to Eclipse Juno and (thankfully) haven't come across this problem in Juno.

Answer (score 0):

Make update android sdk tools, or delete old sdk tools and install new sdk tools.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but all my tools are totally up to date.

Comment: Try delete them, and install new.